# How to display only one fragment tab in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, hide, show-hide

I have different fragments in my `MainActivity`. In each fragment I implemented some features.

Now I am trying to implemented tabs for one fragments, what I'm looking for is about hide tab layout in remaining fragments.

**activity.xml:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.genworks.oppm.MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_search_view_check"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

                <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
                <include layout="@layout/search_toolbar"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>
            </RelativeLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/White"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/White"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Fragment fragment;
    int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST=20;
    Menu search_menu;
    MenuItem item_search;

    ExpandableListView expListView;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    TextView user,firstname,lastname,mobile,role,report_to;
    String user_name;
    ImageView profile;
    private ArrayList<Records> records;
    private ArrayList<Records> recordsList=new ArrayList<>();
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TextView mTitle;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO = 2;
    File mPhotoFile;
    FileCompressor mCompressor;

    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    String sessionId,username,first_name,last_name,mobile_no,role_id,reportto;
    MenuItem refreshMenuItem;
    ExpandableListView expandableList;
    ExpandableListAdapterMenu mMenuAdapter;
    List <ExpandedMenuModel> listDataHeader;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler ( );
    HashMap <ExpandedMenuModel, List <String>> listDataChild;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private boolean ismenutoggle;
    private Toolbar searchtollbar,toolbar;
    boolean needLogin = false;
    LinearLayout dashboard,taskmenu,account,contact,opportunity,logout,documents;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("sessionId");
        username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        PreferenceUtils.getUsername(this);
        PreferenceUtils.getPassword(this);
        first_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("firstname");
        last_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("lastname");
        mobile_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile");
        role_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("role");
        reportto = getIntent().getStringExtra("reportto");
        dashboard=findViewById(R.id.dashboard);
        taskmenu=findViewById(R.id.taskmenu);
        contact=findViewById(R.id.contactmenu);
        opportunity=findViewById(R.id.opportunitymenu);
        account=findViewById(R.id.accountmenu);
        logout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
       // user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        profile=findViewById(R.id.profile);
        mCompressor = new FileCompressor(this);
        firstname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        mobile=findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        role=findViewById(R.id.role);
        report_to=findViewById(R.id.report_to);

        firstname.setText(first_name);
        lastname.setText(last_name);
        mobile.setText(mobile_no);
        role.setText(role_id);
        report_to.setText(reportto);
       // user.setText(username);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      //  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DASHBOARD");

        final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ab.setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_spinner);
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
            mTitle.setText("DASHBOARD");
            mTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
//            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext ().getAssets (), "fonts/astype - Secca Light.otf");
            //          mTitle.setTypeface (typeface);
        }
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        //ab.setTitle ("HOME");

        setSearchtollbar();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        fragment = new DashboardFragement();
        loadFragment(fragment);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent (navigationView);
        }
      //  TextView dashboard=findViewById(R.id.menu_dashboard);
        dashboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTitle.setText("Dashboard");
                fragment = new DashboardFragement();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

      //  TextView task=findViewById(R.id.menu_task);
        taskmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTitle.setText("Task List");
                fragment = new TaskFragement();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTitle.setText("Account List");
                fragment = new AccountFragement();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });
        contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTitle.setText("Contact List");
                fragment = new ContactFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

       // TextView opportunity=findViewById(R.id.menu_opportunity);
        opportunity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mTitle.setText("Opportunity List");
                fragment = new SalesStageFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });


       // TextView logout=findViewById(R.id.menu_logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        initBottomNavigationItems();
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new TaskFragement(), "All");
        adapter.addFragment(new AccountFragement(), "Incomplete");
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), "Scheduled");
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), "Today");
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactFragment(), "Weekwise");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
                "Cancel"};
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    MainActivity.this.requestStoragePermission(true);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    MainActivity.this.requestStoragePermission(false);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

   
    public void initBottomNavigationItems() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment fragment;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.account:
                        mTitle.setText("ACCOUNT LIST");
                        fragment = new AccountFragement();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.task:
                        mTitle.setText("TASK LIST");
                        fragment = new TaskFragement();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.contact:
                        mTitle.setText("CONTACT LIST");
                        fragment = new ContactFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.opportunity:
                        mTitle.setText("OPPORTUNITY LIST");
                        fragment = new SalesStageFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.search).setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        //revision: this don't works, use setOnChildClickListener() and setOnGroupClickListener() above instead
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if(menuItem.isChecked ()){
                            drawerLayout.openDrawer (GravityCompat.START);}
                        else {
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer (GravityCompat.START);
                        }


                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(ismenutoggle==true) {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer (GravityCompat.START);
                    ismenutoggle=false;
                }
                else{

                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer (GravityCompat.START);
                    ismenutoggle=true;
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDrawerItemClickedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            finish();
        }
    }



    private DrawerLayout.DrawerListener mDrawerListener = new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener () {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int status) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideArg) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer (view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer (view);
        }
    };
    public void setSearchtollbar()
    {
        searchtollbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.searchtoolbar);
        if (searchtollbar != null) {
            searchtollbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_search);
            search_menu=searchtollbar.getMenu();

            searchtollbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                        circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                    else
                        searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

            item_search = search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search);

            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item_search, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        circleReveal(R.id.searchtoolbar,1,true,false);
                    }
                    else
                        searchtollbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true;
                }
            });

            initSearchView();


        } else
            Log.d("toolbar", "setSearchtollbar: NULL");
    }

    public void initSearchView()
    {
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) search_menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter_search).getActionView();

        // Enable/Disable Submit button in the keyboard

        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

        // Change search close button image

        ImageView closeButton = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp);
      // closeButton.setImageResource(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplication(), R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp));


        // set hint and the text colors

        EditText txtSearch = ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text));
        txtSearch.setHint("Search..");
        txtSearch.setHintTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        txtSearch.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        // set the cursor

        AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);


        try {
            Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
            mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.search_cursor); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                callSearch(query);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                callSearch(newText);
                return true;
            }

            public void callSearch(String query) {

                Log.i("query", "" + query);

            }

        });

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void circleReveal(int viewID, int posFromRight, boolean containsOverflow, final boolean isShow)
    {
        final View myView = findViewById(viewID);

        int width=myView.getWidth();

        if(posFromRight>0)
            width-=(posFromRight*getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material))-(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_material)/ 2);
        if(containsOverflow)
            width-=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_action_button_min_width_overflow_material);

        int cx=width;
        int cy=myView.getHeight()/2;

        Animator anim;
        if(isShow)
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0,(float)width);
        else
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, (float)width, 0);

        anim.setDuration((long)220);

        // make the view invisible when the animation is done
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if(!isShow)
                {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        // make the view visible and start the animation
        if(isShow)
            myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // start the animation
        anim.start();


    }
    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
      mTitle.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want show only one Fragment then why are you even implementing TabLayout ?

Comment: @chandmohd MainActivity implented tablayout it is applicable to all,form that I can hide the remaining fragements

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if we can create two tabs and when the user presses any of the tab, same fragment should appear instead of multiple fragments. If that is your question, may be i can help.

You will have to create one class that extends FragmentStateAdapter , then you should create a single class that extends Fragment instead of having multiple classes and a layout.

Create ClassFragmentPagerAdapter like this:

```
public class ClassFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
public ClassFragmentPagerAdapter (@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return new ClassFragment ();
    }
    return new ClassFragment ();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Then after that create the other ClassFragment that extends Fragment:

```
public class ClassFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup                         
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_name, container, false);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //do stuff here
}
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)